# Javascript grabbbing a html5 data- value to use as a var

Tags: javascript, html, var

So I want to customize the src via js with hidden data but just can't figure out the right flow to write it. Looking to grab html5 data- to change the src. Any time I have tried to write it can't get it to grab my data- with Var.

referencing question 19320436 for var from data when looking for answers

tried

```html
<html>
<body>

<p id="test" class="customClass" data-newsrc="https://stackoverflow.com"></p>

<script>
var value = $('.customClass').data('newsrc');

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= '<iframe id="myframe" src=""\>\</iframe>';

document.getElementById("myframe").src= value;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

works but is not grabbing a new value from page

```HTML
<html>
<body>

<p id="test" class="customClass" data-newsrc="https://stackoverflow.com"></p>

<script>

var value = "https://stackoverflow.com/qestions"

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= '<iframe id="myframe" src=""></iframe>';

document.getElementById("myframe").src= value;
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `can't get it to grab my data- with Var` ? And what is `question 19320436 f` ? the one where the answer is `42` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select the `#test` element, you'll need it more than once. Without using jQuery you can select the `data-newsrc` property by accessing it from the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.

Instead of writing your HTML in a string, create a new element object with [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), this saves you the step of having to reselect the iframe because you already have a reference.

After setting the `src`, [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) the iframe to the `test` element.

```js
const test = document.getElementById('test');
const src = test.dataset.newsrc;
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = src;
test.append(iframe);
```

```html
<p id="test" class="customClass" data-newsrc="https://stackoverflow.com"></p>
```